# Windows 10 unable to see samba share but Lubuntu can

Tags: samba, windows-10

I have created a samba version 4 share on a Ubuntu 16.04 server, which works fine on my Lubuntu computer, but when I try to access from Windows 10, there are no network connection, even though I am able to ping the server.

All firewalls has been disabled

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the Windows host file

Rightclick the My Computer icon and use Map Netdrive

Use this format:
\\[Name you put in the host file]\[share name]